# How to replace remoteFunction call with jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, grails

Now grails function `remoteFunction` is deprecated so how coudl i change code described [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/wiki/examples) to jquery ajax call? 
Right now i have

```
 function renderChart(){
$.ajax({ 
  url:'${g.createLink( controller:'book', action:'render')}',
  success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        $('#linechart2').html(data);
    }
});
```

but controler returns just js code not rendered chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed it to the following `function renderChart(){
  $( "#linechart" ).load( '${g.createLink( controller:'book', action:'render')}', function(){
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart'], 'callback': drawVisualization});
  });
  }`
but I dont know if it is good solution.